# how to detect when inner html changes in flutter webview

Tags: flutter, dart, webview-flutter

I'm using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)  to view a page from the URL on my Flutter application, what I need to do is to detect when changes happen in the HTML code without changing the URL. as there is some data changing overtime using JS and I need to check for HTML and fetch some data out of it whenever it changes, without the need to use any of

```
 void Function(String)? onPageStarted,
  void Function(String)? onPageFinished,
  void Function(int)? onProgress,
```

because the page is not reloading or the URL is not changing, everything is the same but the HTML code. here is what the Web view looks like:

```dart
WebView(
                            gestureRecognizers: <
                                Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
                              Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                                  () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer()),
                              Factory<HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                                  () => HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer()),
                              Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(
                                  () => ScaleGestureRecognizer()),
                            },
                            zoomEnabled: true,
                            debuggingEnabled: true,
                            initialUrl: controller.mapURL.value,
                            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                            onWebViewCreated:
                                (WebViewController webViewController) {
                              controller.mapWebViewController =
                                  webViewController;
                            },
                          ),
```

and here is how to get the HTML content

```dart
                              var html = await controller.mapWebViewController!
                                  .evaluateJavascript(
                                      "window.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;");
                              print(HTML);
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution to this? I'm looking to do the same thing.

Comment: @Isuru u got any solution?

Comment: @SunishaSindhu I posted an answer below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I somewhat managed to do this by injecting some JavaScript of my own into the webpage and having it send back a message whenever the desired action occur on the page.

In my scenario, I wanted to get notified when a success alert shows up on the web page. I added an event listener for `DOMSubtreeModified` that gets triggered whenever there's a change in the HTML document.

First I create a Javascript channel on the Flutter side. When the page finishes loading, using the `runJavascript` method, I inject the JavaScript snippet.

Now when that alert showed up on the page, the listener functions detects that and send a message back to Flutter using the `postMessage` method.

```
class _MyWebViewState extends State<MyWebView> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
          future: _controller.future,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return WebView(
              initialUrl: widget._buildUrl(),
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              javascriptChannels: _createJavaScriptChannels(context),
              onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) {
                _controller.complete(webViewController);
              },
              onPageFinished: (url) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  snapshot.data!.runJavascript(js);
                }
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Set<JavascriptChannel> _createJavaScriptChannels(BuildContext context) {
    return {
      JavascriptChannel(
        name: 'MobileApp',
        onMessageReceived: (message) {
            if (message.message == 'success') {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(content: Text(message.message)),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    };
  }
}

String js = '''    
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", onDetection);

function onDetection() {
  const successAlertExists =
    document.querySelectorAll("div.alert-success").length > 0;
  if (successAlertExists) {
    MobileApp.postMessage("success");
    
    document.removeEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", onDetection);
  }
}
''';
```

Comment: can u check this once? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73031132/get-the-edited-html-content-in-flutter-inappwebview-using-inner-html

Comment: I don't have much knowledge in javascript. So got confused . Am loading as HTML content only..so am not able to detect that. My use case: I have a webView inside flutter app. Webview renders a HTML content. Page contains html textfields and radio buttons, checkboxes. I want to receive the changes of HTML when we click on submit button. Note: The HTML content is getting from backend. And it's dynamic, so to add onClick in each textfield, radio, checkbox it's not practical. And the same HTML web also using.

Comment: It's done. I will update in my question also. But ur answer helped me. Thanks.

Comment: @SunishaSindhu Glad to hear.