# Get the edited html content in flutter inappwebview using inner HTML

Tags: html, flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I'm using [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) for to load html content. Html content is loading perfect. It has input field, radio, checkbox etc. It's kind of form. So after loading this HTML content I Can edit and submit the HTML response to the backend side. Here am facing an issue, if I try to edit something and try to get inner html or getHtml content am not getting the newly changed html content. It's always getting the loaded html content.
Tried to check this following post [how to detect when inner html changes in flutter webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71310749/how-to-detect-when-inner-html-changes-in-flutter-webview). But no response.

```
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: InAppWebView(
          initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(
              data: '<div id="form-response">' +
                  widget.htmlTemplate +
                  '</div>'),
          initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(javaScriptEnabled: true)),
          onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, url) async {

          },
          onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
            _webViewController = controller;
            _webViewController.addJavaScriptHandler(
                handlerName: 'handleResponse',
                callback: (args) {
                  log('args===$args');
                });
          },
          onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
            print(consoleMessage);
          },
            gestureRecognizers: <
                Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
              Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                      () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer()),
              Factory<HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                      () => HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer()),
              Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(
                      () => ScaleGestureRecognizer()),
            },
        ),
      ),
      GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: () async {
          // var a=await _webViewController.getHtml();
          // print('test1====');
          // log(a!);
          // var html = await _webViewController.evaluateJavascript(
          //     source:
          //         "window.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;");
          var response=getResponse('S');
          log('response$response');
          var html = await _webViewController.evaluateJavascript(
              source: response);
          // "window.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;");
          // String docu = await _webViewController.evaluateJavascript(source:
          // 'document.getElementById("form-response").innerHTML') as String;
          //
          log('test====');
          // log(html);
        },
        child: Text(
          Strings.m081,
          style: AppStyle().regularStyle.copyWith(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: AppStyle.fontSize14,
              color: const Color(0xff1973B9)),
        ),
      )
    ])
```

1. How to get the edited html response?
2. Is it is happening because the controller am calling in `onLoadStop` and `onWebViewCreated`?
3. Is there a way to receive the text changes stream of a webview textfield/radio/checkbox in flutter?
4. Is there in any onstate change for controller?